# flipping only one switch at time

Tags: jquery

I have a css/javascript code that simply flip a switch from on to off and so on,
the problem i'm having is when i want to flip another switch while a previews switch is on i want the previews switch or switches to be turned off.

https://jsfiddle.net/uktoek59/

```
trigger_switch($("#firstSwitch"), 'first switch has been trigger');
trigger_switch($("#secondSwitch"), 'second switch has been trigger');
trigger_switch($("#thirdSwitch"), 'third switch has been trigger');
trigger_switch($("#forthSwitch"), 'forth switch has been trigger');

function trigger_switch(switchId, output) {
  $(switchId).click(function() {
    $(switchId).toggleClass("switchOn");
    alert(output);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use `removeClass()` on the switch elements which are not the one which was clicked. You can achieve this using jQuery's `not()` method. Also note that you can make the logic much more succinct and follow DRY practices by attaching a single event handler and identifying the element which raised the event through the `this` keyword. Here's an example:

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    $('.switch').toggleClass('switchOn').not(this).removeClass('switchOn');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uktoek59/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/he8zsbee/1/

```js
    trigger_switch($("#firstSwitch"), 'first switch has been trigger');
    trigger_switch($("#secondSwitch"), 'second switch has been trigger');
    trigger_switch($("#thirdSwitch"), 'third switch has been trigger');
    trigger_switch($("#forthSwitch"), 'forth switch has been trigger');

    function trigger_switch(switchId, output) {
      $(switchId).click(function() {
        $('.switchOn').toggleClass("switchOn");
        switchId.addClass("switchOn");
        alert(output);
      });
    };
```

```css
    .switch {
      width: 62px;
      height: 32px;
      background: #e5e5e5;
      z-index: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      appearance: none;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 16px;
      -moz-border-radius: 16px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    }
    .switch:before {
      content: ' ';
      position: absolute;
      left: 1px;
      top: 1px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 30px;
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 1;
      border-radius: 16px;
      -moz-border-radius: 16px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    }
    .switch:after {
      content: ' ';
      height: 29px;
      width: 29px;
      border-radius: 28px;
      background: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 1px;
      left: 1px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
      transition-duration: 300ms;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #999999;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #999999;
    }
    .switchOn,
    .switchOn:before {
      background: #4cd964 !important;
    }
    .switchOn:after {
      left: 32px !important;
    }
    .switch {
      width: 100px;
      height: 52px;
      background: #e5e5e5;
      z-index: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      appearance: none;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 53px;
      -moz-border-radius: 53px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 53px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .switch:before {
      content: ' ';
      position: absolute;
      left: 2px;
      top: 2px;
      width: 98px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #e5e5e5;
      z-index: 1;
      border-radius: 52px;
      -moz-border-radius: 52px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
    }
    .switch:after {
      content: ' ';
      height: 33px;
      width: 33px;
      border-radius: 52px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 8px;
      left: 6px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
      transition-duration: 300ms;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #999999;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #d1c7cf;
    }
    .switchOn,
    .switchOn:before {
      background: #00DE68 !important;
    }
    .switchOn:after {
      left: 62px !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters" class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
  <li>
    <p>first switch</p>
    <div class="switch" id="firstSwitch"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>second switch</p>
    <div class="switch" id="secondSwitch"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>third switch</p>
    <div class="switch" id="thirdSwitch"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>forth switch</p>
    <div class="switch" id="forthSwitch"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this help..:)